# How to add different css styles to pages in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, import

I am creating a multi-page application using ReactJS and I want different styles for different pages, especially the logo position.

This is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';

import Login from './user/Login';
import Auth from './user/Auth';
import Home from './user/Home';
import ResetPassword from './user/ResetPassword';
import './App.css';

const App=()=>{
        //ROUTING
 }

export default App;
```

The last imported file always overwrites the styling properties of the entire app. I need to change the position of the logo in each page accordingly and also other things. How do I add different css properties for each page?

Comment: Add a parent class in each file and add `css` under that parent.

Comment: You should use either CSS Modules or styled-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use or module css (for this you have to do changes in webpack).
https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/css-modules-react/
Also you can use package styled components https://www.styled-components.com/
In this case, you have unique styles for all components.

Comment: You don't have to use styles(background color) from the file which overrides, make settings for background color just inside of your components(module css). If in some reason you need background color in that file - try to use ! important inside module css.

Comment: Aso you can add some class above  and make your css more specific (.class1 .class2{background-color:red}). But better don't use this style in your App.css

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder structure as below. And import their own css files. If you are using sass use unique class names. For the 3rd party components, you may need using "!important" in the css files.

```
common/
  Avatar.js
  Avatar.css
feed/
  index.js
  Feed.js
  Feed.css
profile/
  index.js
  Profile.js
  ProfileHeader.js
  ProfileHeader.css
```

and you can read this : https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: I have a lot of files under the user folder. Moreover, I tried this, the last imprted js file's css overwrites all others.

Comment: Using CSS modules will ensure uniqueness so your CSS doesn't get overridden and stays modular. https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet